# Output XML with Freemarker

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

We are using freemarker for templates in our web application. We are using spring's FreeMarkerViewResolver for this.

Is there a way in freemarker to change the content type on the response to

text/xml

is there a way to do this in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it from the template itself, no, but you can inject FreeMarkerViewResolver with a contentType property, and set that to text/xml (or whatever).

If you need different content types for different views, you'll need to configure multiple view resolvers.

Comment: Ah - missed that when I was looking.  It's actually on the UrlBaseViewResolver.